# how to run a c broker example program without using make file?

Tags: c++, apache, messagebroker, qpid

I want to run a  helloworld example in apache qpid c++ broker without using make file is it possible.if so how to proceed and what libraries i need to include?

Answer (score 1):

A make is one tool to automate the build steps. Everything you can do in Makefile can be done on the command line also.

I do not know what is so special about apache an qpid. You should check your compiler and linker manual.

In the end using gcc building hello_world is as easy as
gcc hello_world.c -o hello_world

That's all there is.